# More doubts in bzImage

Tags: linux, kernel, executable, file-format

The description of the `bzImage` in Wikipedia is really confusing me. 
[image]

The above picture is from Wikipedia, but the line next to it is:

> The bzImage file is in a specific
>   format: It contains concatenated
>   bootsect.o + setup.o + misc.o +
>   piggy.o.

I can't find the others (`misc.o` and `piggy.o`) in the image.
I would also like to get more clarity on these object files.

The info on [this post](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/9909.3/0625.html) about why we can't boot a `vmlinux` file is also really confusing me.

Another doubt is regarding the `System.map`. How is it linked to the `bzImage`? I know it contains the symbols of `vmlinux` before creating `bzImage`. But then at the time of booting, how does `bzImage` get attached to the `System.map`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Till Linux 2.6.22, `bzImage` contained:

- bbootsect ([`bootsect.o`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.22.19/arch/i386/boot/bootsect.S)):
- bsetup ([`setup.o`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.22.19/arch/i386/boot/setup.S))
- bvmlinux ([`head.o`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.22.19/arch/i386/boot/compressed/head.S), [`misc.o`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.22.19/arch/i386/boot/compressed/misc.c), `piggy.o`)

Linux 2.6.23 merged bbootsect and bsetup into one ([`header.o`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/arch/x86/boot/header.S)).

At boot up, the kernel needs to initialize some sequences (see the header file above) which are only necessary to bring the system into a desired, usable state. At runtime, those sequences are not important anymore (so why include them into the running kernel?).

`System.map` stands in relation with `vmlinux`, `bzImage` is just the compressed container, out of which `vmlinux` gets extracted at boot time (=> `bzImage` doesn't really care about `System.map`).

Linux 2.5.39 intruduced `CONFIG_KALLSYMS`. If enabled, the kernel keeps it's own map of symbols (`/proc/kallsyms`).

`System.map` is primary used by user space programs like `klogd` and `ksymoops` for debugging purposes.

Where to put `System.map` depends on the user space programs which consults it.
`ksymoops` tries to get the symbol map either from `/proc/ksyms` or `/usr/src/linux/System.map`.
`klogd` searches in `/boot/System.map`, `/System.map` and `/usr/src/linux/System.map`.

Removing `/boot/System.map` generated no problems on a Linux system with kernel 2.6.27.19 .

Comment: So is there any problem if i place the System.map out of boot folder? __bzImage doesn't really care about System.map__ Does that mean both need not lie on the same directory?

Comment: I tried to clarify the answer.